# Select drop-down value based on radio button - dynamic values

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that has all the fields dynamic from database. I have questions/answers kind of form. What I am trying to do is that if a radio button of a question 3 is 'yes', then show a number (ex:5) on drop-down question. I am trying to do this without submitting the form, is ajax the only way?
 Here is the code:

```
<input type="radio" name="YesNo_#Questions.QId#" id="YesNo_#Questions.QId##" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="YesNo_#Questions.QId#" id="YesNo_#Questions.QId#" value="0"/> No

<label class="columnDescription"></label>
   <select name="NumericResponse_#QId#">
     <option value="">Please select</option>
       <cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
         <option>#i#</option>
      </cfloop>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you can have a click event that fires to populate your select.

```
$('input[type=radio][name^=YesNo_]').on('click',function(){
    var fieldId = $(this).attr('name').replace("YesNo_","");
    if ( $(this).val() === "1" ) {
        $('select[name^=NumericResponse_'+fieldId+']').val(5);
    }
});
```

To make this work with your Coldfusion loop, you'll have to add a `value` attribute to the `option`s in your select. Like so:

```
<select name="NumericResponse_#Questions.QId#">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
    <option value="#i#">#i#</option>
  </cfloop>
</select>
```

Hope this helps a bit.